# Сертификат для бота Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, openssl, сертификат

Подскажите как сгенерировать сертификат для бота

1. Генерирую сертификат `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -nodes -days 365 -subj '/CN=111.111.111.111:443'`
2. Устанавливаю Webhook `curl -F "url=https://111.111.111.111:443" -F "certificate=@key.pem" https://api.telegram.org/{TOKEN}/setWebhook`

Результат: `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}`

Но в итоге всё равно ошибка `SSL error {error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}","max_connections":40}`

Что я делаю не так? Который день мучаюсь, но воз и ныне там